# Python and regex - how to find anytext_NUMBER_svm.pkl

Tags: python, regex

I have file names that are in this format:

```
anytext_NUMBER_svm.pkl
```

I need to loop thourgh all files in a dir and file files that look like this:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
anytext_1_svm.pkl
anytext_2_svm.pkl
anytext_3_svm.pkl
```

The matched files will be this:

```
anytext_1_svm.pkl
anytext_2_svm.pkl
anytext_3_svm.pkl
```

How to I use python regex to do this?

Comment: first of all, please show your code... so i know at what scope to help you.

Comment: Why regex? Is not glob.glob sufficient if the pathnames are so simple?

Comment: Well... I will look more into glob.glob.  I never heard of that before.

Comment: agreed....glob.glob is better.  Its now part of my toolkit.  I did ask about regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex shoud solve your problems:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r'.+_\d+_svm\.pkl')
>>> regex.search('anytext_1_svm.pkl') != None
True
```

But you should definitely take a look at the documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: as far as i know you dont need to escape "_" characters?

Answer (score 2):

An option that:

- doesn't use `re`
- makes sure the comparison is only on the filename part - not part of a path
- restricts the number of filename patterns to validate further using `iglob`

Code:

```
from glob import iglob
import os.path
for fname in iglob('*_*_svm.pkl'):
    path, name = os.path.split(fname)
    anytext, digit, rest = name.split('_', 2) 
    if digit.isdigit(): # add criteria for anytext if required...
        # ....
```

Answer (score 0):

regex to catch "anytext_NUMBER_svm.pkl" is very simple.

```
r'.+_\d+_svm\.pkl'
```

Comment: Your regex would also match `'anytext__svm.pkl'` or even `'__svm.pkl'`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a review of this page:
http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/re.html#module-re

It will help you understand how to write regular expressions and ensure that you are matching things properly.  For the number, use [0-9]*, use _ to separate your groups, and write a little match-checking conditional stuff and this will be a quick project.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
file_list = glob.glob('anytext_[0-9]_svm.pk1')
```

Comment: That's also incorrect, it's not the same as regex, `*` will just match any characters.

Comment: I think I understood the fnmatch wrong; but `[0-9]` should match any of numbers, multiple.

Comment: no it only matches one character, although you could leave it like this since OP didn't specify exactly how everything works. I also think by anytext he might mean any characters instead of the text `anytext` itself. Question is vague though

Comment: I think in that respect you could also replace `[0-9]` with `?` right? But I think `?` only means _one of any_ and `*` _many of any_. Not sure if it qualifies it with the character range in `fnmatch`.